# Инициализация класса

Tags: c++, классы, инициализация

В чем разница между способами инициализации?

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int num): val(num) {};

private:
    int val;
};

int main (void)
{
    A a1 = 5;
    A a2{5};
    A a3 = {5};
    A a4(5);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), причем из этих четырех вариантов следует использовать только второй вариант.

Comment: после пустого тела конструктора  точка с запятой синтаксическая ошибка, как и после определения любой функции

Comment: @VTT, а первый и четвертый вариант чем не врианты?  Я знаю, что вы любите фигурные скобки, но это не значит, что все остальное не правильно